# css for all resolution

Tags: html, css

I have already designed my website for the resolution of 1680x1050. However, Because I mostly always use position:absolute, the design is so messy right now(new in css). So, before I start my design again, I decided to ask for professional help. The method i will try to use is making a div element containin all of the contents of the page which is

```
<div style="width:760px;margin: 0 auto;">
...all contents
</div>
```

, to center all of contents of the page. Then, i will redesign my old contents with usign position:relative; left:..px; and top:...px;. I am asking this, because I dont think that width:760px;margin: 0 auto; is centering contents exactly(When I tried this method for an element without anyway left:..px or top:..px, the element is not centered properly). I hope I tell my method well:)  Getting every element from center and place them into where they should be. How can i do this? I dont think this div is doing it:(

Note: I left appropriate empty place in my original design. What i mean is, in resolution of 1680x1050, I did not use about 300px left and right. My design alrady seems centered in 1680x1050.

Comment: is there any styling on the body tag?

Comment: could you show us the code? (both css and html)

Comment: No, there is not. Just that div i am using to style all contents right now

Answer (score 2):

1. never style for screen sizes
2. try to avoid `position:absolute` where ever you can
3. if you need `position:absolute`, try to take % values

why not use it?

1. as you already mentioned, it messes up your code
2. it slows down rendering in the browser
3. elements are taken out of the normal document-flow -> dynamic content may break your layout

if you really need `position:absolute` you can do the following to center an element:

1. specifiy a `width` and `margin:0 auto;`
2. define all offset values, like that:

   `element{
       position:absolute;
       left:10px;
       right:10px;
       top: 10px;
   }`

this would place your element with a "margin" of 10px top,left and right and give it dynamic height.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<div style="width:760px;margin: 0 auto;">
   <div style="position: absolute; width: 760px;">...all contents</div>
</div>
```

Absolute elements position relative the the most immediate absolute positioned parent element, if there are none, it's relative to the document.  But please, don't use inline styles either.  It's also poor practice to design around static resolutions.